# I don't know where forEach() works

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Guys i am sorry to ask this. Maybe a easy one but i am new at this language.

```
let arr =[1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr.forEach(a => a++);
console.log(arr);
```

why doesn't this work?

```
let arr =[
{name:"a"},
{name:"b"},
{name:"c"}
];
arr.forEach(a => a.name = "d");
console.log(arr);
```

but this works?

Answer (score 1):

The value passed to the `.forEach` callback is either passed by value (if it's a primitive type), or effectively as a reference (if it's an object or array).

Your primitive `a++` therefore is modifying a *copy* of the value, and  so does nothing useful.   When you pass an object, though, it's possible to modify the properties of that object, because the (copy of the) reference you're now holding in `a` still refers to the original object.

Answer (score -4):

For each is just a function that loops over the array, by doing a => a++, you are not checking for any condition or having any logic there.
From my understanding what you looking for in .map function, which loops over an array and returns another one

Comment: But it didn't work either.

Comment: You should of assign it to a variable and it will

Comment: you would have had to `return ++a` for a `map` over an array of numbers to work (and also assigned the result of `.map` to a variable that gets logged)